# Swift - How to get type of element of array in generic function

Tags: swift

I need to get type of element inside generic function

```
let array = [String].self          -> Array<String>.Type
let element = array.Element.self   -> String.Type
JSONDecoder().decode(element, from: data) -> works fine

func foo<T>(type: T.Type) where T: Decodable{
    let element = type.Element      ->   Error. How to get element here?
    JSONDecoder().decode(element, from: data)
}

foo(array)
```

How to get element type inside foo function in this example?

Comment: What is Element here?

Comment: String in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works only if `T` is constrained to `Sequence`, because only sequences have an `Element` type.

And you have to add `.self` after `Element`

```
func foo<T>(type: T.Type) where T: Decodable, T : Sequence {
    print(type)
    print(type.Element.self)
}
```

And if you want to decode that type you have to constrain `Element` to `Decodable`, too

```
... where T: Decodable, T : Sequence, T.Element : Decodable
```